# Error: Variable ... must occur on both sides of this | pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I want to write a pattern matching like the follows:

```
match ... with
...
| Const1 (r, c) | Const2 (m, n) 
  -> expr
```

It returns an error: `Error: Variable c must occur on both sides of this | pattern`.

Do I have to write `expr` twice (one time for `Const1`, the other time for `Const2`)? Could anyone help?

Comment: ah, the lost skill of reading error messages..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message said, Or pattern (`| pattern`) requires binding to the same set of variables. Therefore:

```
match ... with
...
| Const1 (m, n) | Const2 (m, n) 
  -> expr
```

or

```
match ... with
...
| Const1 (m, n) | Const2 (n, m) 
  -> expr
```

would work.

Of course, you only can do that if `Const1` and `Const2` accept the same type. In some cases, you still do so if you have parts of constructs with the same type:

```
match ... with
...
| Const1 (m, _) | Const2 (_, m) 
  -> expr
```

The pitfall of Or pattern is that you don't know which constructor you are in. So if logic of `expr` depends on `Const1` or `Const2`, you couldn't use Or pattern anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of why this would be a problem, consider what would happen if `expr` depended on `r` or `c` and the object you were matching happened to be of type `Const2`:

```
let c2 = Const2(1,2) in
match c2 with
...
| Const1 (r,c) | Const2 (m,n) -> r + 1
```

Since `c2` is of type `Const2`, `r` is not defined on the right side of the `->`, so OCaml wouldn't know how to evaluate `r+1`. The compiler catches that this will happen, and makes you change your code to avoid it.

My guess is that `expr` doesn't depend on whether the input is of type `Const1` or `Const2` (otherwise you would have put those cases on separate lines with different expressions), so you might be able to get away with

```
match ... with
...
| Const1 _ | Const2 _ -> expr
```

If you need to match on some field that `Const1` and `Const2` both have, see pad's answer.